# Adding Line Break in XML Contained in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am creating an XML RSS feed using PHP to pull in data from a database. Therefore, my XML is contained in php. I want to add line breaks between every one of these variables in the `<description>` :

```
echo '<item>';
echo '<title>' . $product_name . '</title>';
echo ' <link>http://www.....com</link>';
echo '<description>' . $product_line . ' ' . $product_scale . ' ' . $product_vendor . ' ' . $product_description . ' $' . $buy_price . '</description>';
echo '</item>';
```

I have tried adding `<br >` and `"<br />"` after every variable in the `<description>` tag but that keeps any of the XML/RSS data from running on the page.

I know I can add `<xml>` tags but the format here is different since the XML is being echoed in PHP. Is there a way around adding line breaks in XML that is contained in PHP `echo`?

Here is the entire script if needed:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>

    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <channel>
            <title>Classic Cars RSS</title>
            <atom:link href="http://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" rel ="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
            <description>Classic Cars RSS Feed for learning PHP</description>
            <lastBuildDate><?= $builddate ?></lastBuildDate>
            <language>en-us</language>
        <?php

        define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
        define('DB_PASS', 'x');
        define('DB_NAME', 'x');

        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to database');

        $query = "SELECT productName, productLine, productScale, productVendor, productDescription, buyPrice FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Vintage Cars' OR `productLine` = 'Trains'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                or die('Error querying request');

                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    $product_name = $row['productName'];
                    $product_line = $row['productLine'];
                    $product_scale = $row['productScale'];
                    $product_vendor = $row['productVendor'];
                    $product_description = $row['productDescription'];
                    $buy_price = $row['buyPrice'];

            echo '<item>';
            echo '<title>' . $product_name . '</title>';
            echo ' <link>http://www.test.ishabagha.com</link>';
            echo '<description>' . $product_line . ' ' . $product_scale . ' ' . $product_vendor . ' ' . $product_description . ' $' . $buy_price . '</description>';
            echo '</item>';

          }
        ?>

            </channel>
        </rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single echo with line breaks:

```
echo 'line1
line2';
```

Alternatively use \n

```
echo "line1\nline2"; //you need doublequotes when using \n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo "\n";
```

Whenever you want a new line.